# libsass binding not found in ubuntu

Tags: sass, npm, ionic-framework, libsass, node-sass

I was getting this error while setting up ionic project

`Error: 'libsass' bindings not found. Try reinstalling 'node-sass'?
    at getBinding (/home/ashish/meta-placement-mobile/node_modules/gulp-sass/node_modules/node-sass/lib/index.js:22:11)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ashish/meta-placement-mobile/node_modules/gulp-sass/node_modules/node-sass/lib/index.js:188:23)
    at Module._compile (module.js:434:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:452:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
    at require (module.js:384:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ashish/meta-placement-mobile/node_modules/gulp-sass/index.js:3:17)
    at Module._compile (module.js:434:26)`

I have deleted node_modules and tried to install it via `npm install` but haven't succeeded yet. Please suggest.

System information :
**OS** -Ubuntu 14.04 LTS
**Node** - Nodejs v0.10.25

Comment: did you install gulp-sass ?? `npm install gulp-sass --save-dev`

Comment: @AnasOmar yes i have installed it by using `npm-install`.

Comment: can you please put the package.json content here

Comment: @AnasOmar i have resolved issue by taking rights of the package.json file thanks for you reply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have updated nodejs version to >=0.12.* then libsass binding error get resolve. Updated CLI of ionic suggested to do that.

`sudo npm cache clean -f
 sudo npm install -g n
 sudo n 0.12.7 // for specific version like v0.12.7`